# issue with nested try else statement

Tags: python

I am a beginner programmer and am writing a program that converts letter grades to GPA, or GPA to letter grades as entered by the user. I reference two functions to do the conversions in other programs. I am using the try statement to start by assuming it is a letter grade to convert to GPA, and that doesn't work i try the function to convert from GPA to letter grade.

My program works, the only problem is that my else statement always executes, even if I enter something that is not a letter grade or GPA. I am guessing it is something easy that I am not seeing.

```
#Convert a letter grade to GPA, or GPA to letter grade

from grade_points_to_letter import gpa_converter
from letter_grade_to_grade_point import letter_converter

grade = input('Enter a letter grade or GPA to convert: ')  

while grade != '':
    try:
        grade = grade.upper()
        conversion = letter_converter(grade)
        try:
            conversion = gpa_converter(float(grade))
        except:
            print('You did not enter a valid letter grade or GPA')
    except:
        pass
    else:
        print('Your converted grade is:', conversion)
    grade = input('Enter a letter grade or GPA to convert: ')
```

Comment: I don't think an else statement is meant to be used with a try\except statement.

Comment: my (limited) understanding is that the else statement is only supposed to executed if the try statement worked.

Comment: It means your `try` blocks doesn't throw any error. The only place I can see that might throw an error is in `letter_converter`; what do you have in there?

Comment: It is just a bunch of if statements (programmed much earlier when i was learning if statements....) if it is not one of the letter grades i put in there it just gives up an error

Comment: My thinking is maybe since the first letter function didn't work it went straight to the second try statement.  Maybe it thinks this successful and the else statement triggers?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `finally`?

Comment: And what is the purpose of `letter_converter`? It doesn't seem you are using its result

Comment: As it stands there are several logic errors in this code ... for example, if `conversion = letter_converter(grade)` succeeds, what are you expecting is the next line of code to be executed?

Comment: This is a homework exercise, where they said to write it in a way that first tries to convert from a letter grade to gpa, and if that doesnt work try to convert from a GPA to a letter grade.  all using exceptions.  When the user enters a letter grade, or gpa, it executes properly, but when the user enters something else, it says it is incorrect, and still writes that the converted grade is:

Comment: i dont want it to write that the converted letter grade part if something random is entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner `try-except` will swallow any exceptions, which means that even if `gpa_converter` raises an exception, the outermost `try` suite will still be 'successful' and thus the `else` clause will execute.

There are several ways to fix this, but the way that involves the least amount of refactoring would probably be to re-raise the exception in the innermost `except` clause.

```
while grade != '':
    try:
        grade = grade.upper()
        conversion = letter_converter(grade)
        try:
            conversion = gpa_converter(float(grade))
        except:
            print('You did not enter a valid letter grade or GPA')
            raise 
    except:
        pass
    else:
        print('Your converted grade is:', conversion)
    grade = input('Enter a letter grade or GPA to convert: ')
```

Edit: Okay, based off your comments, what you're actually going for is something like this:

```
while grade != '':
    grade = grade.upper()

    try:
        conversion = letter_converter(grade)
    except Exception:
        try:
            conversion = gpa_converter(float(grade))
        except Exception:
            print('You did not enter a valid letter grade or GPA')
        else:
            print('Your converted grade is:', conversion)
    else:
         print('Your converted grade is:', conversion)            

    grade = input('Enter a letter grade or GPA to convert: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an else statement with try catch. However, checkout how the docs recommends using try catch else. Catch should take an error. You should figure out what kind of error you want to catch.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Another thing you can do is use a debugger to see what you're getting in each block. Just put the following code in the block you want to check out:

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to catch exceptions raised by functions on invalid inputs, probably you would like to rewrite the code to something like this:

```
while grade != '':
    try:
        grade = grade.upper()
        conversion = letter_converter(grade)
    except:
        try:
            conversion = gpa_converter(float(grade))
        except:
            print('You did not enter a valid letter grade or GPA')
            conversion = None
    if conversion:
        print('Your converted grade is:', conversion)
```

Also it is recommended to specify expected exceptions,
for example:

```
except(TypeError, ValueError):
    pass
```

so you won't miss bugs, that you may be not aware of.